# Stream stops after changing orientation (Simulator / Debug)

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-8, streaming, simulator

In my Windows 8 App the Media Element Stream stops playing, after I change the Orientation. When I click on my Play/Pause Button and debug this function (after changing Orientation):

```
public static void playPauseToggleButtonClicked()
    {
        DependencyObject rootGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Window.Current.Content, 0);
        var me = (MediaElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootGrid, 0);
        if (me.CurrentState.ToString() == "Playing")
        {
            me.Pause();
            App.Connector.PlayButtonStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["PlayAppBarButtonStyle"];
        }
        else
        {
            me.Play();
            App.Connector.PlayButtonStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["PauseAppBarButtonStyle"];
        }
    }
```

`me.CurrentState` gives back "`closed`".

I don't know if this only happens because I am in the Simulator, or if this would happen on a Tablet too.

I can't test this on a Tablet because I dont have one. So I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me if this only happens in the simulator or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi MrTouch,
You can not test potrait change scenario on simulator.since there is some bug in simulator when we change simulator orientation mediaelement throws mediafailed exception.Don't worry mediaelement will continue playing media on real device.I had gone through the situation you are currently in.

Comment: Hey NeedForSpeed thanks for your comment. If you would answer my Question with your comment, i could accept your answer. I dont think that I will be the only one asking this :)

Comment: You can upvote my comment.I haven't answered since I lost the msdn link which describes that changing simulator orientation will fire mediafailed event.

Comment: okey, well thanks again :)